# Can't find my home WLAN

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I'm not sure if this the correct place to ask this. (If it is the wrong place, please guide me...)

I just installed my Home WLAN after a reset. Now, I can access it with my smartphone without any problems, but from my computer, I can't find the WLAN. I've such a stick installed on my computer, without any brand name on it:

[image]

Then I inserted an old USB-WLAN Stick by D-Link (DWA-160), and it find it.

So why I can't find the WLAN with this thing above? Maybe because I configurated the WLAN Router over a LAN Cable? Then this undefinied stick can find every single WLAN around my house (it has a very good reachability), but not my home WLAN

I'm about to going crazy...

Some hardware infos:
Os: Windows 8.1
Router: D-Link 645
USB-Stick: D-Link DWA 160

Comment: So when the above pictured device is attached to your PC it sees other available networks except yours, is that correct? If so, then check your router's WLAN settings and ensure your router is set up to broadcast the SSID perhaps?

Comment: @JD87: Yes, it is correct. I see maybe 5 networks except mine. SSID? Sorry, I'm not very familiar with those things. When I'm home, I'll search such ID's and will look if it will work and write back.

Comment: Sorry, the SSID is basically the network name for the WLAN, the name you see when searching for wireless networks. Routers have the option to disable the broadcast of this. If a device has connected to a WLAN before, it will store the details such as the network name/password. If the router is no longer broadcasting the network name and the device already has the settings stored, it can connect, however new devices won't be able to see it.
http://www.dlink.cc/d-link-router/how-to-disable-ssid-broadcast-on-di-624.html

This link shows you have to disable, do the opposite to enable!

Comment: @JD87: I don't think it is because of that. I resetted the router and configured it completely new. My mobile phone and my laptop doesn't have any problems to see and connect to the WLAN. But is it possible to hide the router for exactly one computer?

Comment: Ah okay - I wasn't sure whether or not your other devices just connected automatically to the WLAN, or if they could actually see the network name. My original answer won't be applicable to this then. DO you have the drivers for the unknown adapter? Or is it plug and play? Might be worth reinstalling the drivers for it. If you don't know the model of it to get the drivers, funnily enough I had the exact same problem the other day: 

http://superuser.com/questions/709779/unknown-wireless-usb-adapter-drivers-needed?noredirect=1#comment907179_709779

Comment: @JD87: The network adapter should work good. Before we changed the router, he connects good to all WLAN's. So I think, the adapter should work good...

Answer (score 0):

The thing you pictured is not a Wi-Fi adapter, it is just an antenna, which is just a passive hunk of metal.

Whatever you screwed it onto is probably your Wi-Fi adapter, or at least an antenna cable that connects to your Wi-Fi adapter.

So what's your Wi-Fi adapter?

Comment: Uh. Huh. Right. haha :D Uhm, I'll take a look when I'm home and will write the name of the adapter. So it could be a fault by the configuration of this adapter?